# PyTorch: Why create multiple instances of the same type of layer?

Tags: python, pytorch, instance, dropout

This code is from PyTorch transformer:

```
    self.linear1 = Linear(d_model, dim_feedforward, **factory_kwargs)
    self.dropout = Dropout(dropout)
    self.linear2 = Linear(dim_feedforward, d_model, **factory_kwargs)
    self.norm1 = LayerNorm(d_model, eps=layer_norm_eps, **factory_kwargs)
    self.norm2 = LayerNorm(d_model, eps=layer_norm_eps, **factory_kwargs)
    self.norm3 = LayerNorm(d_model, eps=layer_norm_eps, **factory_kwargs)
    self.dropout1 = Dropout(dropout)
    self.dropout2 = Dropout(dropout)
    self.dropout3 = Dropout(dropout)
```

Why do they add `self.dropout1`, `...2`, `...3` when `self.dropout` already exists and is the exact same function?

Also, what is the difference between (`self.linear1`, `self.linear2`) and `self.linear`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because to separate one Linear layer or Dropout layer from one another. That's very simple logic. You are creating different instances or layers in the network of the Dropout function using `self.dropout = Dropout(dropout)`.

Comment: does "seperate" means that the gradient of linear1 and linear2 is different? what if I don't make multiple instances of layers and just use it multiple time in forward?

Comment: @user1173330 Here separate means different.  If you use multiple times such then how are you going to differ (say) one linear layer from another?

Comment: I think you are not understanding here. They are named differently to differentiate from each other. They are the same Linear layer but they are used multiple times in the network with different names.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of `Dropout`, reusing the layer should not usually be an issue. So you could create a single `self.dropout = Dropout(dropout)` layer and call it multiple times in the `forward` function. But there may be subtle use cases which would behave differently when you do this, such as if you iterate across layers in a network for some reason. [This thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/using-same-dropout-object-for-multiple-drop-out-layers/39027/), and particularly [this post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/using-same-dropout-object-for-multiple-drop-out-layers/39027/6), discuss this in some detail.

For the linear layer, each `Linear` object is characterized by a set of weights and biases. If you call it multiple times in the `forward` function, all the calls will share and optimize the same set of weights. This can have legitimate uses, but is not appropriate when you want multiple linear layers, each with its own set of weights and biases.